# How to check cause of "Unfortunately project has stopped" error?

Tags: android

I want to show an activity in onCreate of main activity. When I run the project on emulator it says "Unfortunately project has stopped".
Is it possible to tell me what's wrong with my code and how should I check the cause of this error every time?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent i = new Intent(this,AppMenu.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Main activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the use of `MainActivity`? You are doing nothing except navigating to AppMenu activity. You can directly launch AppMenuActivity

Comment: you could look at the logcat for more details.

Comment: It seems there is no problem here. ALSO its better to use some button to migrate to another activity  . it may because of your layout.

Comment: @Raghunandan I need that form for future development like splash screen.

Comment: splash screens are considered evil especially if does nothing. http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/

Comment: @M410 Main activity layout is now in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at your Logcat put Breakpoints on your codes then trace it , then if no Success to find out what problem is post your question and Logcat here,but here i think the problem is you didn't define your Activity in **Manifest** file